# Prove $m = n$ for linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

> Let $L: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $\ker(L) = \{0\}$ and $\text{Range }(L) = \mathbb{R}^m$. Prove that $m = n$

So I know that only $L(0) = 0$, and no other $x$ exists such that $L(x) = 0$.

But I am still unsure how to proceed to the desired conclusion?

Comment: Do you know the Rank-Nullity theorem?

Answer (score 3):

$\ker(L) = \{0\}$ implies it is injective, hence $n\leq m.$ Range $L = \mathbb{R}^m$ implies it is surjective, hence $n\geq m.$